# Blender Texture shows in viewport but not in render mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, texture-baking

Everything was working fine for the longest time, then I noticed that my textures were reacting to the world scene. I used some textures from Quixel but of course I downloaded them and they went to my computer.

My doors from Quixel still work, but my walls stopped working then my stairs. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Comment: [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com)